# Intersecting families

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose A, B, C are 3 subsets of the set {1,...,n} Where each pair has nonempty intersect. Is there any intersecting family F from {1,...,n} subsets where F cardinality is equal to 2^(n-1) and F contains A, B and C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $A\cap B\cap C\ne\varnothing$, it’s pretty easy to find such an $F$. If not, there is a $3$-element set $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq[n]$ such that $a\in B\cap C$, $b\in A\cap C$, and $c\in A\cap B$. Let $F$ be the family of all subsets of $[n]$ that contain at least two of the points $a,b$, and $c$.

- Show that $F$ is an intersecting family.
- Use an inclusion-exclusion argument to show that $|F|=2^{n-1}$.

If you get completely stuck, I’ve added a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse over to see it.

> How many subsets of $X$ contain both $a$ and $b$? Both $a$ and $c$? Both $b$ and $c$? If you add these three numbers together, how often have you counted each of the subsets of $X$ that contains all three of $a,b$, and $c$?

Comment: Thank you sir. I don't know How to show F is an intersecting family, i think it is obvious, can you give some hint, tnx

Comment: @Arsalan: Let $U,V\in F$. Each of them contains one of the sets $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, or $\{b,c\}$. If they both contain the same set, then their intersection is certainly non-empty. Now suppose that $U$ contains $\{a,b\}$, and $V$ doesn’t; then $V$ contains either $\{a,c\}$ or $\{b,c\}$, and in either case it intersects $U$. All of the other cases are similar.